# Step by step instructions to make dos "see" and "access" usb hard drives

Tags: usb, boot, external-hard-drive, spinrite

I am stuck with an USB external hard drive (Maxtor 1 Touch) 750GB that crashed. I have photos and home movies (my son's birth, first birthday etc) that are very important to me.

I am given to understand that Spinrite is a very good tool to use, but It does not come "with out of the box" capabilities to access USB drives. If I open the case to get the HDD out from my External HDD, I would compromise the warrenty and I would not be able to exchange the Drive.

I have done a bit of research and have the drivers that could help. But the bit I am missing is, How to put it all together.

I would really appreciate it if some one can give me step by step instruction where I can create a dos boot cd that can load the drivers and assign a drive letter to it so that I can make Dos "See" the external hard drive.

I have a Toshiba satellite laptop that runs Windows XP (Home). It does not have a floppy drive.

I will be greatful to your help in the regard.

Answer (score 2):

even if you're able to get this drive working with [DOS USB support](http://www.freedos.org/freedos/news/newsitem/149.html), it will take SpinRite weeks if not months to complete the job.

if you have access to a desktop PC, remove the drive from its enclosure and connect it to the SATA controller, SpinRite should be able to detect the disk now.

alternatively, use **[HDD Regenerator](http://www.dposoft.net/)** instead, it is faster and works within a Windows environment.

Answer (score 2):

It's a long shot, but maybe if you [contact Seagate](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/about/contact_us) and explain the situation **prior** to opening the drive, they could make an exception for you so you can recover your data.  It certainly can't be the first time they've ever heard that request and the worst they can say is no.